# When is an edit considered enough to be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, editing

A mod edited one of my questions I've made today (For the curious: [Class Object to create objects of type Object, in a dynamic way, with magic methods](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86009/class-object-to-create-objects-of-type-object-in-a-dynamic-way-with-magic-meth)).

The changes are so minimal that I have no idea how and why the edit was accepted (maybe because he is a mod and his edits don't wait in the pool?).

The edit was very basic:

- 1 line removed
- 1 `t` added to a word (my keyboard at work eats letters when I type too fast)

Is this an acceptable edit? Or should it be a comment instead?

When is it considered enough changes for an edit to be considered valid?

Answer (score 15):

Moderators have no restriction on edits that they can make. There is no technical reason that it would have had to go through a review, or be accepted. Additionally, there is no minimum edit restriction either, like there are for other users.

So, aside from technical reasons to restrict the edit, was it a good one?

I believe so, there was a spelling/typo error that was corrected, there was redundant use of "The code:" (when it was obvious that there was code after that), and then there were multiple paragraphs merged in to a simpler description.

So, the edits improved your post.

We encourage all edits to improve posts, and this is a Stack Exchange thing:

- [SE Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/)
- [Meta SE Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239898/new-three-tiered-badge-idea-explainer-refiner-illuminator)

Edits that make improvements to questions are encouraged.

Note that, [with the editing privilege](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), there's the following:

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - **to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes**
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
>   change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

^^ Bold is my emphasis. About the footnote *"...make the post substantively better..."*, fixing a typo is substantive enough on Code Review.

Comment: It's probably also important to note that such a minimal edit would be frowned upon if the post were quite old (as it bumps the posts), but given it was edited same day, it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I agree with 90% of what you said. Except the part where you say that it improved the question. Also, you said that "there were multiple paragraphs merged in to a simpler description". That is actually a big. If you check the initial version, they were already in that format. Boiling down, I think the edit would be better off as a comment due to the abcense of improvement, but I also wanted an opinion from someone who's "above" me. I've upvoted anyway because most of what you say is correct. But honestly, I don't see any substancial improvement that justify an edit.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, if you read the blog that was linked to, you'll see that the bar for edits is "any improvement what so ever". Was your post improved at all? If so, it's a good edit. No matter who made the edit.

Comment: @RubberDuck I don't mind edits. In fact, I thank them when I see that they actually improved the question/answer. But, in your opinion, do you think that the edit improved the quality so much that it is the difference between a bad question and a good one?

Comment: About *"Moderators have no restriction on edits that they can make."* and *"there is no minimum edit restriction either, like there are for other users."* These things apply to all 1k+ users I believe, and it is important to note that there's no such thing as a 'too minor' edit (see my answer)

Comment: Do note we often have the discussion about minor edits pushing questions back to the top of the queue. In light of that, I can totally understand why this question is asked.

Answer (score 10):

Let's get one thing straight:

#### There's no such thing as 'too minor' edit anymore.

When approving or rejecting edits, there used to be a "too minor" reason for rejection. This reason does not exist anymore.

*Additionally*, 1k+ users do not need to have their edits approved.

[image: List of suggested edit rejection reasons]

Comment: This answer probably needs an explanation of "completely superfluous".  Obviously the OP will argue that the edits in question fall under this category.